# Is there a way to input any data types in a function c++?

Tags: c++

In C# and Java you are able to input any type of data -int,string,float,long- without excluding another type.

So i'm wondering is there any way to do that in C++ ?

Because unlike in C# Or Java, Object or Obj Doesn't work, and frankly I've been searching for a while and haven't came to a conclusion.

The Function\Method i'm trying to use is to take any input from integers,strings etc... or\and user input and print it back into the console.

the code is :

```
static void P(Object x) { cout << x;}
```

Comment: The concept you're looking for is called *templates*.

Comment: How do you know the object you're passing is printable?

Comment: `std::cout << x;` already prints any `x` to the console, why do you need `P`?

Comment: I've just started in C++ and i just wanted to wrap my head around functions \ methods and how they compare to Java.

Comment: I use this method to pass between methods and the user, so i would know that what the user is gonna input is gonna be compatible ...else it just prints an error string and restarts it from the nearest point.

Answer (score 4):

With template:

```
template <typename T>
void Print(const T& x)
{
    std::cout << x;
}
```

with usage:

```
Print(42); // int
Print("Hello world"); // const char (&)[N]
Print('*'); // char
Print(4.2); // double
// ...
```